# Can't reboot after installing new ubuntu

Tags: reboot

For some reason I cannot boot my computer I have two different Ubuntu installations in my grub (version 2.02 beta2-15ubuntu0.1)

I have the 3.16.041 generic Kernel and 14.04.2 LTS but idk much about coding and I don't have internet access other than my phone.

The original Windows 7 is on the computer but I got it at a pawn shop so I don't have the Windows 7 password.

Comment: Does it boot from install Live disc ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem installing Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I tried to dual boot my lap with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. All installed perfectly. After installation, Ubuntu  requested a restart. So I chose the option *restart now*. I waited more than 45 minutes but there was no response at all.  So i did it manually by hitting the power button.

Afterwards, it works well. Then ubuntu archive show me some updates, which I installed. After install it showed restart now. When I clicked that, it hung again.

This happened on a Dell I5 1.8GHz 320 HDD and 4 GB ram.

But then I bought a new pc . HP I3 2.8GHz 1Tb HDD with 4 GB ram. Now I have set up dual booting again,  this time with windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. Now it all works perfectly.

**I suggest you to check your system wheather its capable to Dual boot**

***This may be not correct answer, I post this for get some idea with the system***